# Conditionally Remove Character of a Vector Element in R

Tags: regex, r, string, character

I have (sometimes incomplete) data on addresses that looks like this:

```
data <- c("1600 Pennsylvania Avenue, Washington DC", 
          ",Siem Reap,FC,", "11 Wall Street, New York, NY", ",Addis Ababa,FC,")
```

I need to remove the first and/or last character if either one of them are a comma.

So far, I have:

```
for(i in 1:length(data)){
  lastchar <- nchar(data[i])
  sec2last <- nchar(data[i]) - 1
  if(regexpr(",",data[i])[1] == 1){
    data[i] <- substr(data[i],2, lastchar)
  }
  if(regexpr(",",data[i])[1] == nchar(data[i])){
    data[i] <- substr(data[i],1, sec2last)
  }
}

data
```

which works for the first character, but not the last character. How can I modify the second `if` statement or otherwise accomplish my goal?

Comment: You could also do `gsub("^,(.*),$","\\1", data)`

Comment: Thank you @akrun, it's good to learn this different ways of pattern matching. It's my weak suit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try the below code which remove the comma present at the start or at the end,

```
> data <- c("1600 Pennsylvania Avenue, Washington DC", 
+           ",Siem Reap,FC,", "11 Wall Street, New York, NY", ",Addis Ababa,FC,")
> gsub("(?<=^),|,(?=$)", "", data, perl=TRUE)
[1] "1600 Pennsylvania Avenue, Washington DC"
[2] "Siem Reap,FC"                           
[3] "11 Wall Street, New York, NY"           
[4] "Addis Ababa,FC"
```

**Pattern explanation:**

- `(?<=^),` In regex `(?<=)` called positive look-behind. In our case it asserts What precedes the comma must be a line start `^`. So it matches the starting comma.
- `|` Logical OR operator usually used to combine(ie, ORing) two regexes.
- `,(?=$)` Lookahead aseerts that what follows comma must be a line end `$`. So it matches the comma present at the line end.

Comment: I really appreciate this solution. At the risk of being needy, I wonder if you could possibly explain the logic/regex a bit? I'm trying to figure it out so that I'll be more independent.

Comment: Thanks again; much appreciated! I'm sure that others will also learn from this thanks to the Pattern Explanation.