# How to remove certain special character occurrences from some elements in a vector?

Tags: r

I have a vector filled with some numbers that I read from a .csv file, but some of those numbers are preceded by a * ,that is,

```
12 34 *89 *45 34
```

I want to remove the * from  these elements while retaining their types, that is

```
12 34 89 45 34
```

How do I do this?

Comment: no I have read it from a csv file, but for simplicity I wrote this here

Comment: Are there any decimal numerics in there, or just integers?

Comment: @RichardScriven : The elements were not strings when read from csv file, please remove that edit.

Comment: Just integers are there, but some of them are preceded by *

Comment: @RichardScriven : I edited my question

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Conditionally Remove Character of a Vector Element in R](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25432828/conditionally-remove-character-of-a-vector-element-in-r)

Comment: @Hack-R :  That doesn't address my question, because there strings are addressed, but here I am having integers, and I want to retain them as integers, as I mentioned in the question.

Comment: @SoulRayder they aren't integers while they have characters in them, but you can convert them to integers after taking the characters out with `as.numeric()` or `as.integer()` before using them further...

Comment: How about `as.integer(scan(text = "12 34 *89 *45 34", quote = "*", what = ""))`?  Or for your file `as.integer(scan(file, quote = "*", what = ""))`

Comment: @Hack-R: Yes I know, these numbers have to be cleaned, but they are to be treated as numbers, so I am trying to clean the numbers before using them.

Comment: @RichardScriven that should do the trick

Comment: @StevenBeaupré : Thanks, your solution seems to work.

Comment: @RichardScriven : I already have that data in a vector. Could you please modify your answer for a vector instead of a file?

Comment: @SoulRayder - That comment shows both.  Try `text = x`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
as.integer(stringi::stri_extract_all(x, regex = "[[:digit:]]+", simplify = TRUE))
```

Which gives:

```
#[1] 12 34 89 45 34
```

Comment: Thanks . Could you please explain that line? I am new to R, and could not follow.

Comment: Have a look at `?stringi::stri_extract_all`